# ANY? expected input to be an agentset but got the number 0 instead

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to select the closest free carrier to the cutter and send them to retrieve a metal sheet from delivery for the cutter to cut. This is the relevant code:

```
globals[
  metal-sheets
  cutter-closest-free-carrier]
breed[carriers carrier]`
```

```
to cut  
  let free-carriers carriers with [laden = false]  
  let cutter patches with [machine-type = "cutter"] 
  let delivery patches with [area = "delivery"]  

  ask cutter [
  if status = "import" [
      set cutter-closest-free-carrier min-one-of free-carriers[distance myself]]   ]

  if any? cutter-closest-free-carrier[
      ask cutter-closest-free-carrier [
      face delivery 
      fd 0.01
      set metal-sheets cars-here
      if any? metal-sheets [
        create-link-to one-of metal-sheets [tie]
        face cutter
        fd 0.01
        ask cutter[set status "pending"]] 
    ]    
  ]
end
```

The error message I get is:

"ANY? expected input to be an agentset but got the number 0 instead."

How can I make this function in the intended way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the error is with this:

```
if any? cutter-closest-free-carrier[
```

As a global variable, `cutter-closest-free-carrier` is initialized by NetLogo to zero.  If in

```
ask cutter [
  if status = "import" [
      set cutter-closest-free-carrier min-one-of free-carriers[distance myself]]   ]
```

`status` is not equal to "import", then `cutter-closest-free-carrier` will still be zero when you apply `any?` to it.  Thus the error. There is another problem too - `any?` should be applied to agentsets and even if `status = "import"`, `cutter-closest-free-carrier` will be a single agent as a result of `min-one-of`, not an agentset.

So, first initialize `cutter-closest-free-carrier` to `nobody`, either in your setup or at the beginning of `to cut`.  Then change the test for there being a `cutter-closest-free-carrier` to

```
if cutter-closest-free-carrier != nobody [
```

I think that should do it.

Hope this helps,
Charles